# Exibir itens de um determinado ID usando GET angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb

Estou fazendo um fórum bem basico onde o usuario digita o titulo, assunto e descricao do topico, e este é enviado para o mongo (também estou usando o postman), com ajuda do pessoal daqui em outro topico, esta parte ja finalizei. No index aparece todos os topicos cadastrados e um botão de acessar para visualizar determinado topico, ou seja cada topico tem um id. 
A duvida é: como exibir cada item de determinado id? 
Abaixo segueo que ja fiz, com a ajuda de alguns usuarios daqui:

Obs: _id é o codigo do topico

```js
function ListaTopicosController($scope, $http) {

...

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('forumList', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

   $scope.carregarDados = function() {
      var url = 'http://localhost:3000/topico/lista'
      $http.get(url, {id: $scope.data._id}).then(
            function successCallback(resposta) {
               $scope.forum.titulo = resposta.data.titulo;
            },
            function errorCallback(resposta) {
            }
        );
   }
}]);
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ListaTopicosController" >
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1><font color="#00c6d7">ALLDISPOR</font></h1>
    <p>Fórum de Discussão</p>
  </div>
  
 
 
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-controller="forumList" ng-init="carregarDados()">
 <h2>{{ forum.titulo }}</h2>
 <h4> {{ forum.assunto }}</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Pra responder sua pergunta preciso de algumas informações a mais. Primeiramente, você poderia dar um exemplo de como os tópicos estão organizados no banco de dados? Isso pode ser feito com db.<nome_da_coleção>.findOne()

Comment: Segundo, você poderia mostrar o código da url que você está mandando requisição GET (http://localhost:3000/topico/lista)?